# How do I get variables from Android Manifest in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use the API key for the Google Maps API in my package, assuming it's present in the AndroidManifest file (and the iOS equivalent). I see that if you use the `google_maps_flutter` package, you never have to pass the API key to the `GoogleMap` widget. Currently, I'm passing the API Key as an attribute to every widget I use, like this:

`// The class receives the API key through a property called apiKey
SearchPlaceWidget(apiKey: YOUR_API_KEY);`

And I'd like something like this:

`// The class will get the API key directly from the AndroidManifest file
SeachPlaceWidget()`

Answer (score 3):

You can't get variables from `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Here is what you can do, create a new file in your `lib` folder say `strings.dart`, in that file.

Write this in your newly created `lib/strings.dart`

```
final String apiKey = "your_api_key";
```

And wherever you want to use the API key, simply import `lib/strings.dart` file, and use it like:

```
SearchPlaceWidget(apiKey: apiKey);
```

Comment: How does the GoogleMap widget access it though? Directly from the native language (Java for Android and Obj-C for iOS)?  In my case, since I'm making this a package, using this solution wouldn't be the best (passing it as one of the parameters to the widget constructor is better).

Comment: Are you working natively in java code? If yes, you already have `strings.xml` file, you can add above String there, and use it like `getString(R.string.api_key)`

Comment: I am not working on native code. I'll open a feature request in the flutter GitHub for them to make an easy API so we can access AndroidManifest (and the iOS equivalent) global variables.

Comment: `GoogleMap` widget can access it like I mentioned `SearchPlaceWidget`, all you need to do is import the `strings.dart` file and use `apiKey`

Comment: In this case it didn't help, since I'm making this a package for anyone to use, it's easier to just ask for the api key in the widget constructor. Thanks for the help though.